# Devise and polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to build an app with devise which provides one sign in and sign out interface but multiple sign up interfaces depending on the model to sign up. Thus I came across polymorphic associations which fit my needs very well because I would like to have separate tables for the different models.

But I'm not able to sign up any user because I always get some error with the attributes of the base user model. I've read https://stackoverflow.com/a/11956734/1183192 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/15459313/1183192 and I think I adapted everything.

Base user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_id, :role_type,
                  :salutation, :firstname, :lastname, :street, :zipcode, :city, :phone

  belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true

  def customer?
    'Customer' == self.role_type
  end

  def customer
    Customer.find(self.role_id) if self.customer?
  end

  def admin?
    'Admin' == self.role_type
  end

  def admin
    Admin.find(self.role_id) if self.admin?
  end
end
```

Customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :role
  attr_accessible :user_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Customer controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  # removed all methods except new and create

  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    @customer.build_user

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customer }
    end
  end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @customer, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

View (new.html.erb):

```
<h1>New customer</h1>

<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for @customer.user do |u| %>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :email %>
          <%= u.email_field :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :password %>
          <%= u.password_field :password, required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :password_confirmation %>
          <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation, required: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :salutation %>
          <%= u.text_field :salutation %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :firstname %>
          <%= u.text_field :firstname %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :lastname %>
          <%= u.text_field :lastname %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :street %>
          <%= u.text_field :street %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :zipcode %>
          <%= u.text_field :zipcode %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :city %>
          <%= u.text_field :city %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
          <%= u.label :phone %>
          <%= u.text_field :phone %>
        </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit class: "button success" %>
<% end %>
```

The new page renders correct but when I try to submit I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in CustomersController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user
```

Parameters are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"WngmLBR7MmVuhDyYxsASWQscUTB/VFmKmn/fdatVB30=",
 "customer"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"max@mustermann.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "salutation"=>"",
 "firstname"=>"Max",
 "lastname"=>"Mustermann",
 "street"=>"Musterstraße 1",
 "zipcode"=>"12345",
 "city"=>"Musterstadt",
 "phone"=>"4917620289872"}},
 "commit"=>"Create Customer"}
```

I think the error is in the Customer class but I don't know how to fix it.

### Update

I've made a change to the customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :role
  attr_accessible :user # :user instead of :user_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Now I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in CustomersController#create
User(#70271634657140) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70271609254480)

app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:44:in `new'
app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:44:in `create'
```

Comment: Paste your `Garage` model code.

Comment: your parameters being sent in are `"customer"=>{"user"=>{` but they should be `"customer"=>{"user_attributes"=>{"` ... you might need to post the view code for the form that creates the user to help diagnose.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in your view:

```
f.fields_for :user do |u|
#...
```

instead of

```
f.fields_for @customer.user do |u|
```

Error occurs because nested attributes root should be "user_attributes", not "user".

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you
replace
`attr_accessible :user_attributes` 
To
`attr_accessible :user`

in that customer model

Better ways:---

application.rb there is config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

Please refer [Mass assignment protection](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/148-protect-mass-assignment)

Thnaks in advance

Comment: This gives me another error:

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in CustomersController#create
User(#70271634398080) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70271609254480)

Comment: config.active_record.whitelist_attributes is set to true

Comment: This is association error mass assignment error will not be shown from now. Please check the association customer has_one :user so user belongs_to :customer but in your user model user belongs_to :role Thanks